# How do I recognize an empty JSON object in JS returned by my Rails controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, render

How do I check for an empty JSON object in Javascript?  I thought the key was

```
var isEmpty = (response || []).length === 0;
```

but this isn't it.  In my JS console, I have tried

```
jsonresp = {}
{}
jsonresp.length
undefined
```

What's driving this is I have a Ruby on Rails controller that is returning the following

```
render json: job_id.eql?(cur_job_id) ? {} : json_obj
```

In the case where the controller returns the "{}" is where I'm having trouble on the JS side recognizing if it is empty or not.

Comment: `if(Object.keys({}).length > 0){console.log("YaY")}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` function to get keys of the object as an array and then check the array to see whether it is empty.

```js
var obj = {};
var arr = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(arr);
console.log("Is Empty : " + (arr.length == 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
if (typeof jsonresp == 'undefined' || typeof jsonresp == 'null'){

// some logic here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly:

`const isEmpty = !Object.keys(jsonresp).length`

Comment: thanks for changing - almost downvoted :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn hope it helped you :)

Comment: Your first answer didn't help because it was blatantly wrong!! But you edited and corrected it...so all it good.